# Opening and closing modal in Angular with Animation

Tags: angular, animation, dialog

I am trying to create a modal that slides in from the bottom and closes with slide down animation. Was hoping to use `https://animate.style/`

Managed to achieve opening animation by adding to this.dialog.open

```
panelClass: ['animate__animated', 'animate__slideInUp']
```

but how do I animate closing it?

As of now I ran out of ideas. Was hoping someone could suggest a way.

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  modalActive = false;
  opening = false;
  closing = false;

  showModal(){
    this.modalActive = true;
    this.opening = true;
  }

  closeModal(){
    this.closing = true;
    const t = setTimeout(() => {
      clearTimeout(t);
      this.modalActive = false;
      this.closing = false;
      this.opening = false;
    }, 500)
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="showModal()">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal" [ngClass]="{ active: modalActive }">
  <div
    class="modal-content-wrapper"
    [ngClass]="{
      'animate__animated animate__slideInUp': opening,
      animate__slideOutDown: closing
    }"
  >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div>hello</div>
      <button (click)="closeModal()">Close Modal</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;  
}

.modal.active{
  display: block;
}

.modal .modal-content-wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal .modal-content{  
  width: 500px;
  background: white;  
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```